# Adding a search field on blog in Magento

Tags: php, magento, search, magento-1.7

I'm looking to add a search field for a blog on one of our websites which is powered by Magento. We currently use a third party add-on - http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/free-stuff/blog.html I've contacted aheadworks and the blog doesn't come with a search capability. However they said I could use something like http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/advanced-search.html but I’m not sure if this is there sales team trying to flog us another product.

I'm new to PHP and even newer to Magento so really looking for some advice. Is it something I can build myself with relative ease? Or it something like the plugin they've recommend something I should be heading towards?

I'd like the search results to output on a separate template, to one where the blog posts are listed. I've googled for a while now and all I can find if a product search.

Just a little bit of info on how the blog currently works. There are two pages on the site where there different blog posts show, and depending on the category you select when adding a post. This will determine which page the post is then pulled through on.

Any help would be much appreciated...

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically solution that can take you 5mins to implement:

In /app/code/community/AW/Blog/Block/Collection.php replace public function getPosts(); with:

```
public function getPosts()
{

    $collection = parent::_prepareCollection();

    $tag = $this->getRequest()->getParam('tag');

    if ($tag) {
        $collection->addTagFilter(urldecode($tag));
    }


    //this part here is responsible for search

    $search = $this->getRequest()->getParam('search'); //get request "search" parameter from url

    if ($search) {
        $collection->searchBy(urldecode($search));
    }

    //end

    parent::_processCollection($collection);

    return $collection;
}
```

After that, add following code in: /app/code/community/AW/Blog/Model/Mysql4/Blog/Collection.php CREATE FUNCTION searchBy()

```
public function searchBy($key)
{         
    $this->getSelect()
            ->where("(title) LIKE '%$key%' OR (short_content) LIKE '%$key%'");

    return $this;
}
```

Though it's not perfect solution but it's doing it's job you can improve MySql query in way you want it.

Now when you go to: http://example.com/blog?search=keywords

Blog will display with posts which includes particular keywords.

Hope it helps.

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion for you, to use the "Google Custom Search Integration By Solwin" Magento Extension.

Key Features:

- Use Google Search Algorithms
- Helps to increase SEO for your site
- Works in Multi-store environments
- Improve your google search result with images
- Setup the Google Custom Search Engine to search through multiple websites of yours.
- Easily enable/disable from admin
- Customize the No. of records per page
- Enable/disable Image Search
- All you need to do is to fill in the Search Engine Unique ID
- Easy replacement with your buil-in search functionality
- Admin can enable/disable the autocomplete feature – which makes querying even faster.
- Enable 'Order By' dropdown from admin
- Easy to configure

You can easily install this extension.
Here you can take a look at ["Google Custom Search Integration By Solwin"](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/google-custom-search-integration-by-solwin.html)